# Xunit test fails with NU1701

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nuget, xunit

I try to get my unit tests for Xamarin to run, but fail to get it working. I added the following nuget packages to my project:

- MSTest.TestAdapter
- MSTest.TestFramework
- xunit

I can see my unit tests in the list of tests. But when I start to run a single test I get the following message:

> No test matches the given testcase filter FullyQualifiedName= ...

After researching a bit I found in the *Build* section this message:

> Warning NU1701: Package 'MSTest.TestAdapter 1.4.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

How can I get my tests running?

EDIT: I uninstalled the MSTest Nuget from the project and got the following:

> No test matches the given testcase filter

EDIT 2: The test looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using App.Services;
using Xunit;

namespace App.Tests.Services
{
  public class HelperTest
  {
    [Fact]
    public void Encrypt_password_Test()
    {
      string password = "Helloworld";
      string expectedResult = "";
      string result = Helpers.Encrypt_password(password);

      Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect that the test will fail, because of the empty string.

The csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-GB</NeutralLanguage>
    <AssemblyName>App</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>App</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.5.231" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.581479" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker" Version="2.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <XliffResource Include="MultilingualResources\App.de.xlf" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Localizations\AppResources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Views\Login\NewProfilePage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NewProfilePage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Localizations\AppResources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Settings\AppSettings.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Login\NewProfilePage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Settings\ProfilelistPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Settings\ProfilePage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\ProjectPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Settings\SensorListPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\SensorTestPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\Settings\SettingsPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Tests\Projectlist\" />
    <Folder Include="Tests\Settings\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I also created a example xunit test project. There I noticed that it uses *netcoreapp2.1* as TargetFramework. When I change the TargetFramework in my app it makes it incompatible with Xamarin.

Comment: IT might be getting confused about the fact you've got both xunit and MSTest installed in the project. They're two different test frameworks. Uninstall one and try again.

Comment: I uninstalled the MSTest Nuget. You can see the result in the edit.

Comment: Do you have at least 1 method with a `[Fact]` or `[Theory]` attribute, and it's a public method on a public class? I think xunit doesn't discover private methods or classes.

Comment: Yes. The class is public and the Fact methode is also public. The tests are discovered and I can see them in the list of tests on the side.

Comment: If you can create and share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be tremendously helpful. My only wild guess at this point is that the test runner is incompatible with your project's assemby. If your project is only compiled for x86 and the test runner runs x64, or maybe your project is only compling for ARM, then the test runner can't run it. Although, in this case I'd expect a different error message.

Comment: I added the source code of one test in the second edit. To compile the project I choose Any CPU and compile for the Intel x64 Android Emulator.

Comment: The csproj is still relevant. If I create a new xunit project from the new project template, create a `Helpers.Encrupt_password` file to make this compile, it works for me. Your sample is missing the complete and reproducible parts from the doc I linked to.

Comment: Added csproj. I noticed that it might depend on the TargetFramework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly found the solution yourself. Indeed the reason the tests are not running is because `netstandard` target frameworks are not executable. `netstandard` is a contract, but it needs a runtime such as `netcoreapp`, the .NET Framework (`net472` for example), Xamarin, or others. Tests were being discovered by static analysis, not by execution.

The usual way people write tests for their code is to put tests in a separate project. This also means when you ship your app to customers, the dlls they install don't have test code that will never run and just make the download larger for no reason.

So, create a xunit test project. Ideally it targets the same runtime that your app is going to run on, but I've never done any Xamarin development so I don't know if that's feasible, so maybe `netcoreapp2.1` or `netcoreapp2.2` is good enough. If you're using Visual Studio, [add a project reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019#projects-tab), otherwise edit the csproj and add `<ProjectReference Include="../path/to/project.csproj" />`.

If your production code has internal classes that you don't want to make public, then add the [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to your production assembly, and it will be available just to your test assembly.